# w3wp.exe (NETWORK SERVICE user) prevents access to file

Tags: .net, iis, w3wp

I have a web service application, that uses another application which save and load an xml file.

After three accesses to the file, the file cannot be accessed again. If i kill the w3wp.exe process that belongs to the NETWORK SERVICE user everything starts working again but for one time.

Here is the sample of the code which saves and load the xml file.

```
    public void saveXmlFile(string filename)
    {
        if (vsqlschema == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tried export data without schema");
            //TODO: Messagebox
            return;
        }
        FileStream fs = null;

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(vsqlSchema));
            fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            serializer.Serialize(fs, vsqlschema);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IO Error: {0}", e.Message);
            //TODO: Messagebox
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                fs.Close();
                fs.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public XmlDocument loadXml(string filename)
    {
        //XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
        //xrs.XmlResolver = null;
        //xrs.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            //using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(filename))
            //using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr, xrs))
            using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filename)){
                xdoc.Load(reader);  


                    reader.Close();

            }   

        }
        catch (XmlException xe)
        {
            errors.Add(string.Format("Line: {0}, Position: {1}::: {2}", xe.LineNumber, xe.LinePosition, xe.Message));
        }

        return xdoc;
    }
```

Any ideas what is going on and what can be the solution of this

Comment: by "file cannot be accessed again", what exactly do you mean? Access denied? Open handles? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Loading the file returns null because it is already opened by the w3wp.exe

Answer (score 1):

There seems be a race condition accessing the file. You should lock the file for writing and allow others to modify it while reading.

To achieve this, you'll also need fine grain control over the FileStream class constructors, specifing the rigth paramters for each case to allow or not modifying the file while reading with System.IO.FileShare enumeration values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cssfs8c4.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx

I don't know if it's completely necessary or not, but I also like to call Stream.Flush() before Close()

Comment: Flush is not only good behaviour but often necessary - many types of stream won't write the last chunk unless they're flushed before closing which can lead to some interesting problems.